# Exception handling - Is there a better way?

Tags: model-view-controller, asp.net-mvc-2, exception

public bool AddEntity(int parentId, string description)
        {
            try
            {
                _connection.Open();
                SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("INSERT Structure (Path,Description) " +
                                                    "VALUES(" + GetPath(parentId) + ".GetDescendant(" + GetLastChildPath(parentId, 1) + ", NULL), " +
                                                    description + ")", _connection);

```
            if (command.ExecuteNonQuery() <= 0) _success = false;

            command.Connection.Close();

            if (_success)
            {
                return true;
            }

            throw new Exception("An error has occured whilst trying to add a entity");
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            AddError(new ErrorModel("An error has occured whilst trying to add a entity", ErrorHelper.ErrorTypes.Critical, ex));
            return false;
        }
    }
```

Is there a better way of handling the exceptions in the example above?

Thanks in advance for any help.

Clare

Comment: in addition to Rob Stevenson-Leggetts answer, I'd also make the catch-exception more specific. for instance catching an SqlException first, because that will contain more specific information about the actual error and the stacktrace.

Leave the catch(Exception ex) as the last catch-block.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's quite a few things wrong here.

a. You're using inline SQL and injecting what I can only assume to be user generated data into it. This is a security risk. Use a [parameterised query](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/database/sql_in_csharp.aspx).

b. You're exception handling is ok but this will leave the connection open if an error occurs. I'd write it like so:

```
 public bool AddEntity(int parentId, string description)
 {
    try
    {
        //Assuming you have a string field called connection string
        using(SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(_connectionString))
        {
            SqlParameter descriptionParam = new SqlParameter("@description", SqlDbType.VarChar, 11);
            descriptionParam.Value = description;

            SqlParameter parentIdParam = new SqlParameter("@parentId", SqlDbType.Int, 4);
            parentIdParam.Value = parentId;

            //Bit confused about the GetPath bit.
            SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("INSERT Structure (Path,Description) " +
                                            "VALUES(" + GetPath(parentId) + ".GetDescendant(" + GetLastChildPath(parentId, 1) + ", NULL),@description)", conn);

            command.Parameters.Add(descriptionParam);

            if (command.ExecuteNonQuery() <= 0) _success = false;
        }

        if (_success)
        {
            return true;
        }

        //This isn't really an exception. You know an error has a occured handle it properly here.
        throw new Exception("An error has occured whilst trying to add a entity");
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        AddError(new ErrorModel("An error has occured whilst trying to add a entity", ErrorHelper.ErrorTypes.Critical, ex));
        return false;
    }
```

Comment: +1 for parameterised query.  I knew this existed, but didn't know exactly what it was called, or where to look :)

Comment: Thanks for this Rob, quick question how do I handle the SqlException?

Answer (score 2):

You can take advantage of the IDisposable interface, and the power of a `using` block.

```
using(var connection = new Connection()) // Not sure what _connection is, in this method, so making pseudo-code
{
  // ... work with connection
}
```

This will close the connection even if an exception is thrown.  It turns into (more-or-less) this:

```
var connection = new Connection();

try
{
  // ... work with connection
}
finally
{
  connection.Dispose();
}
```

Dispose, in this case, will close the connection.